# Displaying property with Horizontal and Vertical Stack View in Swift

Tags: swift, uistackview

I am new to swift . I am following the programmatic approach to create the view . I created two stack view . One is horizontal and other one is vertical. Into horizontal stack view I want to display the label property  and Vertical stack view I want to display the Image. I want to display the **image on left side and label properties on right side.**

Here is the code I used ..

```
import UIKit

class PeopleCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    static let identifier = "PeopleCell"
    
    private lazy var mainStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .center
        return stackView
    }()
    private lazy var lastnameTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var firstnameTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var peopleImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       // imageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        return imageView
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        setUpUI()
    }
   
    
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configureCell(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        firstnameTitleLabel.text = "Firstname :\(firstName)"
        lastnameTitleLabel.text = "Lastname : \(lastName)"
        
        }
        
    
    func configureImageCell(row: Int, viewModel: ViewModel) {
        
        peopleImageView.image = nil
        
        viewModel
            .downloadImage(row: row) { [weak self] data in
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self?.peopleImageView.image = image
            }
    }
    
    private func setUpUI() {
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(lastnameTitleLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(firstnameTitleLabel)
        
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(peopleImageView)
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(stackView)
        
        contentView.addSubview(mainStackView)
        
        // constraints
        let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        
        peopleImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        peopleImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot ..

[image: result]

Here is the expected result.

[image: expected output]

Comment: it might be problems with set up height and width of these stack view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you have your `.axis` properties reversed.

You want your `mainStackView.axis` to be `.horizontal` and your `stackView.axis` to be `.vertical`.

Also, these two lines are not needed (and cause problems):

```
// don't do this
//stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
//stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStackView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

As a side note, instead of:

```
let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
```

you may want to use:

```
let safeArea = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
```

which gives you the default cell margins.

---

**Edit**

```
// this is the "main" stack view with
//   the image on the left
//   the labels on the right
// so it needs to be HORIZONTAL
private lazy var mainStackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.axis = .horizontal

    stackView.distribution = .fill
    return stackView
}()

// this is the "labels" stack view with
//   two (or more) labels from top down
// so it needs to be VERTICAL
private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.axis = .vertical

    stackView.distribution = .fill
    return stackView
}()
```

Comment: I deleted the lines and let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide already present into code . Still same result

Comment: @Amzad - did you change the axis on your stack vies?

Comment: Where actually I needs to make changes please ?

Comment: @Amzad - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thanks you. Now I got it